# Sidebar nav - click outside of side nav that closes the sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I am using this sidebar (https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation) and when the user clicks outside of navbar how can I have it close the bar instead of closing via the x.

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var trigger = $('.hamburger');
        var overlay = $('.overlay');
        var wrapperEl = $('#wrapper');
        var isClosed = false;

        function hamburger_cross() {
            if (isClosed === true) {
                overlay.hide();
                trigger.removeClass('is-open').addClass('is-closed');
                isClosed = false;
            } else {
                overlay.show();
                trigger.removeClass('is-closed').addClass('is-open');
                isClosed = true;
            }
        }

        trigger.click(function () {
            hamburger_cross();
        });

        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            wrapperEl.toggleClass('toggled');
        });
    });
```

Full working snipped can be found here:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ex8ddv5q/811/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.add(overlay).click(function () {
      hamburger_cross(); 
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: ...but I arrived before with the same solution... :'(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.add(overlay).click(function () {
      hamburger_cross(); 
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }

  /*$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });  */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside the `hamburger_cross()` function block

```
// on document click...
$(document).on("click",function() {
    // If mobile nav is open...
    if (isClosed === true) {
        // Close
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open').addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this, but as far as I can see it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add this line at the end

```
$('.overlay').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution on my Joomla 3.9.18 websites:

The javascript for opening and closing the nav and also closing the overlay is this:

```
function openNav() {document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "310px"; 
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

In the index.php file the overlay div opening tag is this:

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="closeNav()">
```

So it uses the same javascript as the standard 'X' closure.

The html code to open the sidenav:

```
<div id="burger" class="burger" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&nbsp;</div>
```

and to close it with a conventional 'X':

```
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="responsivebar" style="none" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
</div>
```